# TextView with marquee_forever attribute, don't move horizontally on new elements

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

The first list of elements correctly show the marquee effect, however the elements that I add later after receiving a notification from Firebase do not present the marquee effect in a TextView.

**MyActivity.java**

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRecycler = findViewById(R.id.choices_recycler);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecycler.setAdapter(new ChoiceAdapter(this, getChoices()));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int insertIndex = 0;
            choices.add(insertIndex, new Choice('foo1','foo2'));
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(insertIndex);//New elements don't marquee automatically
            //adapter.notifydatasetchanged();//This works! New marquee elements start moving, but OLD elements stop with this...
      }
    };

}
```

The new elements are inserted correctly with the design they should, however the only thing that does not work in the new elements is the movement of the marquee. Here is part of the .XML:

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_separator"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Here the marquee text" />
<!-- I've also tried: focusableintouchmode=true and focusable=true -->
```

I'm also using TextView.setSelected() in my ViewHolder, but not working on new elements.

Any help will be more than appreciated!

***UPDATE#1***
I just tried one thing, and that is that if I minimize the App to the background and reopen it and bring it to the foreground, the marquees do work.
Also if I pull down the top notification bar and then go back to my App, the marquees work.

***UPDATE#2*** I have tried this and unfortunately it has not worked for me either, although it looked good: https://gist.github.com/LeonardoCardoso/1116723900c815a48496

***UPDATE#3*** MyAdapter:

```
public class ChoiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private final Activity activity;
    private List<Choice> choices;

    public ChoiceAdapter(Activity activity, List<Choice> choices) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.choices = choices;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_choice, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder1(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d("onBindViewHolder", "onBindViewHolder executed");
        Choice choice = choices.get(position);
        ViewHolder1 viewHolder1 = (ViewHolder1)holder;
        viewHolder1.bind(choice);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return choices.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView titleText;
        private final TextView dateText;

        public ViewHolder1(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titleText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            dateText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_date);
            dateText.setSelected(true);
        }

        public void bind(final Choice choice) {
            titleText.setText(choice.title);
            dateText.setText(choice.date);
        }
    }


}
```

***UPDATE#4*** Live example - The first four items are inserted when starting the App, and your dial works correctly.

The items that appear are added when receiving calls to Firebase Clod Messaging:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZi4S.jpg

1) 4 elements are loaded in the RecyclerView when starting the App, and their marquee have the correct animation

2) Later we are adding NEW elements, but they do not present the animation in the TextView marquee

3) If I pull down the notification bar or send the App to the background and go back to it, all the marquee works mysteriously

Comment: Maybe post also your adapter and the rest of the layout, since I tried a simple case with `setSelected` and it seems to work.

Comment: @MarcinJedynak thanks, you're right! I have updated the question and added the Adapter, I am trying to make an example in Android Studio and upload it